# DRYing the controller in Phoenix

Tags: controller, elixir, phoenix-framework, dry

in my controller I have `current_company` and `current_user. User must send the current company with every request.

So I thought, user needs to send it in the header.

so in one request, I have token (jwt) and company. Now in my controller I have

```
 def action(conn, _) do
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
      [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
  end
```

Which I am extracting the `current_user` then in my function call: `def show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) do` I use it, now I have to use 
`company = conn.assigns.current_company` in order to get current company in each function.

All are working fine, I wanted to see if there is a DRY solution like the one I did for the current_user so I don't need to repeat it all over my controller.

Thanks

Comment: Just add `conn.assigns.current_company` to that list when you call `apply`?

Comment: Do you mean like this: `apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
      [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user, conn.assigns.current_company]` ?

Comment: Yes. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I get `function Web.AssetController.show/4 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:` error. Here is the show: `show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) `

Comment: Update the function you are calling as well (`show` in this case, and all others.)

Comment: It worked! sorry, I thought all of the function calls in controller are set and can not be changed, so now I understand that they are standard functions like any other functions in Elixir. Cool. ( Please make your comment into a respond ) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any number of terms to the list you pass as the last argument to `apply`. `apply` will call the relevant function with as many arguments as in that list. So, you can do:

```
apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
  [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user, conn.assigns.current_company])
```

and then change all the action functions in that module to accept 4 arguments. The fourth one will now be the current company value.